Can I use GridDb with Entity Framework Core 6?
Can I use GridDB in Entity Framework Core 6? I have a set of entities related to an IOT project that were created using the code-first approach.
Now, I want to migrate the database from SQL Server to GridDB. Is there a GridDB Entity Framework Core provider that facilitates seamless communication between GridDB and supports performant transactional queries?
I’ve searched a plethora of sites and documentation available on GridDB but still found no clue on how I can use it with Entity Framework Core.


Can I use GridDB in Entity Framework Core 6?

No.

There are no (literally zero) NuGet libraries available for GridDb.

...let alone ADO.NET Providres for GridDB.
...let alone Entity Framework Providers for GridDB.
...let alone Entity Framework Migrations Support for GridDB.


Furthermore, GridDb's developers don't support Windows as a platform (excepting under WSL), so it's reasonable to assume that supporting .NET is not in their priorities.
Also, why EF Core 6? We're on EF Core 8 now.


Now, I want to migrate the database from MSSQL to GridDB. Is there a GridDB Entity Framework Core provider that facilitates seamless communication between GridDB and supports performant transactional queries?

Forgive me for editorialising, but because MSSQL and GridDB are entirely different in all the ways that matter I don't understand how you could decide to switch from MSSQL to GridDB: GridDB isn't suitable for the kinds of things a traditional RDBMS is meant for; and GridDB is designed around completely different database paradigms and operating constraints (GridDB is for low-power/embedded/IoT devices, running in-memory, churning through time-series data with reduced data-integrity guarantees; while MSSQL is a client/server, disk-based RDBMS that runs on beefy-boxes with hundreds of gigabytes of RAM, etc.

I want to migrate the database from MSSQL to GridDB.

Such a migration cannot be performed automatically and requires careful planning.

Is there a GridDB Entity Framework Core provider that facilitates seamless communication between GridDB and [unrelated run-on sentence]

This is not a valid question: "between" is a preposition requiring two subjects: the first is GridDB, but the second is undefined.

supports performant transactional queries?


You are not asking a well-researched question: queries are read-only operations that do not require transactions unless you're executing queries while DML/store/write-operations happen concurrently.
If you're asking about the the performance of OLTP workloads, then the choice of client-library or API will have very little to do with actual runtime performance: that's more dependent on your actual workload, lock contention, memory and disk speed, and more besides.
Given that GridDB only supports transactions over containers (i.e. tables), that means they don't support row-level locking or key-range locking; GridDB also doesn't seem to support any kind of snapshot-isolation, which means GridDB likely will exhibit very poor runtime performance under combined OLAP+OLTP workloads (i.e. running SELECT queries concurrerntly with INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements).
It also only claims partial support for SQL-92, with no mention of later SQL standards, and I haven't seen evidence of support for more modern set-based DML (though they recently advertise adding support for batched SQL INSERT - but the article doesn't demonstrate any actual SQL INSERT statements, just Kafka and Python).


I’ve searched a plethora of sites and documentation available on GridDB but still found no clue on how I can use it with Entity Framework Core.

Your search was unsuccessful because this isn't a well-supported scenario - and I strongly suspect that's simply because it's a very ill-considered idea.

I do want to state that I'm not bashing GridDB here: I'm sure GridDB is a great product for doing what it's designed for: handling time-series data on low-power/IoT devices; whereas that's something MSSQL definitely cannot do (e.g., right now my SQL2022 box needs half a terabyte of RAM just to get out of bed in the morning, ugggghhh).
